# Convert WAV to FLAC with libFLAC in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, flac

I've tried to port the [libFLAC encoding example](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/examples/c/encode/file/main.c?view=markup) to C# and came up with this code:

```
public class LibFLAC {

    public static void Test() {
        string inputPath = Path.Combine("D:\\", "_", "test.pcm");
        string outputPath = Path.Combine("D:\\", "_", "test.flac");

        uint channels = 2;
        uint bitsPerSample = 16;
        uint sampleRate = 44100;


        IntPtr encoder = FLAC__stream_encoder_new();
        if (encoder == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("Encoder: NEW failed");

        bool ok = true;
        ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels(encoder, channels);
        ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample(encoder, bitsPerSample);
        ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate(encoder, sampleRate);
        ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_compression_level(encoder, 5);
        // ok &= FLAC__stream_encoder_set_verify(encoder, true);
        if (!ok) throw new Exception("Encoder: SET failed");

        int status = FLAC__stream_encoder_init_file(encoder, outputPath, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (status != 0) throw new Exception("Encoder: INIT FILE failed");


        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            uint bps = bitsPerSample / 8;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[channels * bps * 1024];
            Int32[] pcm = new Int32[channels * 1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < read / bps; i++) {
                    pcm[i] = (Int32) (((uint) buffer[i * 2 + 1] << 8) | (uint) buffer[i * 2]);
                }

                ok = FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved(encoder, pcm, (uint) (read / bps / channels));
                if (!ok) throw new Exception("Encoder: PROCESS INTERLEAVED failed ::: " + FLAC__stream_encoder_get_state(encoder) + " ::: " + FLAC__stream_encoder_get_verify_decoder_state(encoder));
            }

            ok = FLAC__stream_encoder_finish(encoder);
            if (!ok) throw new Exception("Encoder: FINISH failed");

            FLAC__stream_encoder_delete(encoder);
            encoder = IntPtr.Zero;
        }



        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nDone");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr FLAC__stream_encoder_new();

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void FLAC__stream_encoder_delete(IntPtr encoder);


    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_set_verify(IntPtr encoder, bool value);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_set_channels(IntPtr encoder, uint value);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_set_bits_per_sample(IntPtr encoder, uint value);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_set_sample_rate(IntPtr encoder, uint value);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_set_compression_level(IntPtr encoder, uint value);


    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int FLAC__stream_encoder_init_file(IntPtr encoder, string filename, IntPtr progress_callback, IntPtr client_data);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved(IntPtr encoder, Int32[] buffer, uint samples);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern bool FLAC__stream_encoder_finish(IntPtr encoder);


    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int FLAC__stream_encoder_get_state(IntPtr encoder);

    [DllImport("libFLAC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int FLAC__stream_encoder_get_verify_decoder_state(IntPtr encoder);

}
```

The `test.pcm` file is raw PCM data without WAV or RIFF headers and in the given format (2 channels, 16 bps and 44.1 kHz).

The code works and the FLAC plays normaly, but the created file is almost as big as the source wav (WAV: 47MB --> FLAC: 45MB) and there are 200ms noise at the end. If I send it through the FLAC Frontend GUI with the same settings I get a 35MB file, so the WAV should be OK.

Also, if I enable `FLAC__stream_encoder_set_verify`, the program immediately fails at `FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved` with

- `FLAC__StreamEncoderState = 4` (VERIFY_MISMATCH_IN_AUDIO_DATA - *The verify decoder detected a mismatch between the original audio signal and the decoded audio signal.*) and
- `FLAC__StreamDecoderState = 3` (READ_FRAME - *The decoder is ready to or is in the process of reading a frame.*)

which makes no sense?

Did I missed something or made a mistake in the conversion?

Comment: Your ok &= .... style is no good. You need to check each and every return value and bail out as soon as one fails.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, I'm not going to do this in the main code. This was just a quick test if the conversion works.